# PHP New Line after n commas

Tags: php

I want to insert a new line after n commas.
For example I got this value: `385,386,387,388,389,390,391,392,393,394,395,396,397,398,399,400,401,402,403,404,405,406,407,408,409,410,411,412,413,414,415,416,417,418,419,420,421,422,423,424,425,426`

How I could echo them all, but every 5th comma there should be a linebreak?

`385,386,387,388,389,
390,391,392,393,394,
395,396,397,398,399,
400,401,402,403,404,
405,406,407,408,409,
410,411,412,413,414,
415,416,417,418,419,
420,421,422,423,424,
425,426`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You should try and post atleast some sort of code, It shows that you have tried something instead of just posting question to get answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one method:

```
// Get all numbers
$numbers = explode(',', $str);
// Split into groups of 5 (n)
$lines = array_chunk($numbers, 5);
// Format each line as comma delimited
$formattedLines = array_map(function ($row) { return implode(',', $row); }, $lines);
// Format groups into new lines with commas at the end of each line (except the last)
$output = implode(",\n", $formattedLines);
```

Comment: You could remove the `. ','` in the `array_map()` call and add it in the final bit `implode(",\n"`

Comment: One of the best methods

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

1. You can explode the string with commas and check for every 5th
   position there should be a line break.
2. You can check it with dividing key with 5.(i.e) it will give you a
       remainder of 0
3. Please note that key starts from 0, so I have added (key+1), to make it start from 1

   ```
   $string = "385,386,387,388,389,390,391,392,393,394,395,396,397,398,399,400,401,402,403,404,405,406,407,408,409,410,411,412,413,414,415,416,417,418,419,420,421,422,423,424,425,426";    
   $stringexplode = explode(",", $string);
   $countstringexplode = count($stringexplode);
   foreach($stringexplode as $key => $val)
   {
       $keyIncrement = $key+1;
       echo $val.($countstringexplode == $keyIncrement ? "" : ",") ;
       if(($keyIncrement) % 5 == 0)
       echo "<br>";
   }


        ?>
   ```

Comment: I tried also with explode, but failed on counting the array items up.
this is working like a charme

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
//Start //Add this code if your values in string like that
$string = "385,386,387,388,389,390,391,392,393,394,395,396,397,398,399,400,401,402,403,404,405,406,407,408,409,410,411,412,413,414,415,416,417,418,419,420,421,422,423,424,425,426";
$string_array = explode(',', $string);
//End //Add this code if your values in string like that

//If you have values in array then direct use below code skip above code and replace $string_array variable with yours 

end($string_array);        
$last = key($string_array);

foreach ($string_array as $key => $value) {
    if($last==$key){
        echo $value;
    }else{
        echo $value.',';
    }
    if(($key+1)%5==0){
        echo "<br />";
    }
}

?>
```